# transform a 3d array to a matrix and keep the dimnames

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a array with specific colnames. 
I am trying to transform this array to a matrix. 
How can I transform it to a **3x9** matrix by keeping the colnames ?

**Replicable data:**

```
test <- structure(c(0.375273574511523, 0.333640287506392, 0.349192797931677, 
                    0.337219826870885, 0.318182584380369, 0.320214135918515, 0.361795340513871, 
                    0.303301639079779, 0.308995818880145, 0.486614010203226, 0.491666372158188, 
                    0.450500424965387, 0.464697136076233, 0.467426609239434, 0.475098558417684, 
                    0.467056879901411, 0.43139438188378, 0.452656403568038, 0.451463478297646, 
                    0.516198183913922, 0.522289371444439, 0.499669539425807, 0.527507832814278, 
                    0.529443687671795, 0.520999085947043, 0.526833049499385, 0.533862568866946
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("100", "200", "300"
), c("3", "4", "5"), c("0.025", "0.05", "0.075")))
```

**Desired output** *(only the first and second dimension dimnames needs to be keept) the 3d dimnames (0.025, 0.05 and 0.075 can be removed).*

[image]

Comment: You want to have duplicated column names? Which are numbers?

Comment: Yeah I want to duplicate the column name. But they are not necessary numbers. For instance, I could have writen a3, a4, a5 instead 3,4, 5   x100,x200,x300 instead 100 200 300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Probably need some extra effort to take care of the duplicated column names though.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:3, function(i) test[,,i]))

            3         4         5         3         4         5         3
100 0.3752736 0.3372198 0.3617953 0.4866140 0.4646971 0.4670569 0.4514635
200 0.3336403 0.3181826 0.3033016 0.4916664 0.4674266 0.4313944 0.5161982
300 0.3491928 0.3202141 0.3089958 0.4505004 0.4750986 0.4526564 0.5222894
            4         5
100 0.4996695 0.5209991
200 0.5275078 0.5268330
300 0.5294437 0.5338626
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for. :)